# Unable to click parent Activity button when PopupWindow showing

Tags: android, popup

In my parent Activity i've a button, when i click on it shows PopUpWindow with 2 ImageButton.. When this PopUpWindow exists 'm unable click my parent activity Button.. Here is my code, is there any problem in it..

```
public class PopUpExample extends Activity {

    Button but;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    PopupWindow popUp;
    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);     
        but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn);     

        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                View popView;

                if(click){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                    popUp = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false),100, 50, true);
                    popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    popUp.update();
                    click = false;

                    popView = popUp.getContentView();

                    ImageButton call = (ImageButton) popView.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);   

                    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {                           
                            Toast.makeText(PopUpExample.this, "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton sms = (ImageButton) popView.findViewById(R.id.sms_btn); 

                    sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {                           
                            Toast.makeText(PopUpExample.this, "Sms...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    popUp.dismiss();
                    click = true;
                }                       

            }    
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popview when created takes away focus from the mainView so the user is not able to click the elements which are on the main view.

To click on the main view one need to dismiss popview first.

With respect to the above theory in your code You trying to dismiss popview by clicking on the button which is at main activity which is not possible.

Below code has the changes which you need to incorporate in your above code

```
public class PopUpExample extends Activity {    
    Button but;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    PopupWindow popUp;
    //boolean click = true;
    View popView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);     
        but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn);     

        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // if(click){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                    popUp = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false),100, 50, true);
                    popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    popUp.update();
                    //click = false;

                    popView = popUp.getContentView();

                    ImageButton call = (ImageButton)popView.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);   

                    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {                           
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            popUp.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton sms = (ImageButton)popView.findViewById(R.id.sms_btn); 

                    sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {                           
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sms...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            popUp.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

               //}else{
                   // popUp.dismiss();
                 // click = true;
               // }                       

            }    
        });
}
}
```

Comment: Just use   popupWindow.setFocusable(false); ,  popwindow dismiss and background  view  click with will  work same  time .

Answer (score 0):

To enable the activity button, you must close the popup window .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, Sorry for answering my question.. In this line

```
popUp = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false),100, 50, true);
```

it means...

```
PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable);
```

i set focusable as true so its blocking parent view.. So when i set it to false i got access to click parentview button..:)

Answer (score 0):

Another easiest way is

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      Button but;
     LinearLayout mainLayout;
     PopupWindow popUp;

        @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);      
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin);   
        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater =       
       (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
       View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);  
             final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow (popupView,   
             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
             popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
       ImageButton call = (ImageButton)   
             popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);   

    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {                           
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    ImageButton sms = (ImageButton) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2); 

    sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {                           
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sms...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });


   }
   });
    }
}
```

main2.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/lin" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/openpopup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open Popup Window" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working  for me set   popupWindow.setFocusable(false);, background and  popwindow  dismiss  will  work same time